# How do I get rid of the extra 'Figure [x]' caption under my figure?

Tags: captions

I have two projects on Overleaf, a dissertation and a paper extracted from the dissertation. The former has a figure which is perfect, with a caption above that says 'Figure 2.2', the figure in the right position, and the citation underneath. The code for that is the same in the article, and I put the same packages and image files as well. However, for some reason the article says 'Figure 2' on top of the figure, and 'Figure 3' followed by the citation underneath it. I don't know why this extra caption of 'Figure 3' appears in the article. The following is the code at the start of the article, followed by the code for the figure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\usepackage{citesort}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\sloppy

\vspace{5mm}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Rubber Hand Illusion}
    \includegraphics{Rubber Hand.jpg}
    \caption{\citep[p. 4]{Metzinger}}
    \label{fig:rubber_hand}
\end{figure}
```

Update: I ended up changing the style because I found out my citation style (APA) has guidelines on how to caption figures, and this wasn't in line with that. Now I just need to figure out how to change the font of the 'Figure 2', if that's possible, and the font size of the whole thing.

Update 2: It worked. In my first attempt I was able to get the desired font style and size. B)

Comment: I should mention that when I remove the second '\caption{}' thing, then it changes the position of the figure and citation (moves the figure left and citation right).

Comment: In your code fragment you require additional caption below figure.

Comment: You don't need a \caption to display text.  Just add a \par or blank line where needed.

Comment: Well you provide two `\caption` commands so why are you surprised that two captions are printed? Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

- If you have the same code for figure in your thesis and your article, than you should got the same result in the botsdh case. So, about this your question is unclear.
- I suspect, that by second caption you like inform readers a source of images.
- For those information you can use ``copyrightbox `package`. You may liked such solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}   % <---


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Rubber Hand Illusion}
    \label{fig:rubber_hand}
\copyrightbox[b]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}{Source: \citep[p. 4]{Metzinger}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you like to change style of the  "source"  you can do this by:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\CRB@setcopyrightparagraphstyle}{\centerin}% raggedleft
\renewcommand{\CRB@setcopyrightfont}%
    {\scriptsize\color{black}}
\makeatother
```